# How to create different user inputs in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

So I have a scenario where a couple of users go to the specified website, login, then give some text input (literally enter some text).

Now, the problem is that the script initially recorded **my** input and now every user in the thread group simply repeats my actions and everybody enters the same input (mine).

What I need to achieve is that every user enters his own unique input. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parameterize the input variable.

Use "[CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)" to provide the input.

https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!